# How to do Javascript access a local database in txt format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie working on a 100% js prototype. It consist of 3 docs: an html page full of xml tags, a small dictionary in a text file format, and a js file with jquery.

The js needs to parse the xml tags (no problem here) and look into the mini-dictionary list for available translations.

Which is the best way to implement the mini-dictionary list. (No more than 50.000 records). Is there a way to load the list into a memory database and access it from js? Which is the usual path to take in this case? What is the simplest and machine-independent way to do this?

Any directions as to where should I research are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this JS in the browser? If not, what server side JS is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest encoding mini-dictionary with JSON data format, and then using AJAX to get that file and parse it. But then you are risking someone will just copy whole dictionary and **steal** your work.

That is, if you are not using server side language, like PHP. If you are using it, then just store everything into **database** and request **just specific words** with AJAX.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to load it with AJAX, it could just be included as a `.js` file.

Comment: Great idea! Yes, but as I said, then someone will just copy everything like 1-2-3 if he doesn't use server side service. You know that I mean?

Comment: That's not what the OP is concerned with. The OP appears to want it to run entirely in the browser, without server scripts, and has not mentioned anything about being worried someone would steal the database.

Comment: Well, he maybe is, but he doesn't know it yet :D

Comment: No worry about stealing since this is an extract of a much bigger dataset, and the ownership of this mini-dictionary goes to the client of the 100% app. This is to be a complete solution to run in the client without server interaction. Thanks Jared and Rok.

Comment: Yes, then JSON is ideal, because Javascript natively supports it. Thanks you too.